# What is the simplest way of tracking issues and ToDo 's using Git?

Tags: git, issue-tracking, todo

Is there any *built in* issue tracking or ToDo tracking with `git`?

Or is there a *simple way* to easily manage tasks and bugs using git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know many people just keep a text file in the repository. This is a cool idea because, well, since GIT is a source control system, looking at the TODO file through commits over time reveals work that you've accomplished. In other words, using GIT you can see your progress through time through things like TODO files and design files. You're looking for a simple way of managing TODOs? I'd say just throw a TODO.txt file into the repo; it doesn't get much simpler than that!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking i'd do if there were no better built-in functions. Maybe there's something more comprehensive? maybe not :)

Comment: +1, this is an excellent bare-bones way to track TODOs, especially for small projects, and it doesn't require anything beyond `git`.